# Convert compressed sparse matrix to dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

When trying to turn a roughly (2,000,000x3) array of one hot encoded values into a data frame I encounter a 'DataFrame constructor not properly called!' error.

I've also explicitly tried wrapping the array in np.asarray() but get an 'Must pass 2-d input' error.

```
enc = skp.OneHotEncoder()
X_ismale = enc.fit_transform(X.IsMaleBucket.values.reshape(-1,1))
X_ismale = pd.DataFrame(X_ismale,columns=['IsMale_'+str(i) for i in np.sort(X.IsMaleBucket.unique())])
```

X_ismale has type:

```
<2256308x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2256308 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Error is as previously described.

I expect an errorless conversion to dataframe but can't get it.

Comment: Pandas cannot work with sparse matrices, only with dense data. You can use [`to_array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.toarray.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.toarray) to convert the sparse matrix to a dense array.

Comment: Pandas has its own sparse format.

Answer (score -1):

Pandas cannot work with sparse matrices, only with dense data. You can use to_array to convert the sparse matrix to a dense array. – jdehesa 9 mins ago

Using to_array worked although the current version turned out to be toarray.

Thanks.

Comment: `toarray` (or `M.A` for short) creates a dense array.  This can be a problem if the resulting array is too large for memory.  A major reason for using sparse matrices is they can use less memory.   Of course a full dataframe with all these zeros could also be too large from memory.